# Why this JQuery load doesn't last more than an instant

Tags: jquery, html, load

This is the code I'm using:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org        /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">

</head>

<body>
<script src="script/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {



$("#a").click(function(){
   $("#content").load('index.html');
});


});
</script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="a">
     <a href="">Primero</a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="">Segundo</a>   
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="">Tercero</a>
 </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to load this html page on the div 'content':

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
<embed src="">

 </embed>
</nav>

INDEX
</body>
</html>
```

But it only loads for less than a second. Why is that? I thought it should last more than a fraction of second. I hoped that it will remain stable after loaded.

My aim is to use this technique to load html pages within a website using a reference page with menu and titles, footer and basic information that should be shown in the whole website at any moment. Like this, if I ever had to change some text on the footer or title of my whole website, I just have to come on this principal html instead of having to change all the code in all the pages of my website, that would be quite a tedious and unconfortable work.

All of this effort is prepared to run websites in a server without apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty href will reload the page, and any changes done with javascript will be gone.

Either change the anchors:

```
<a href="#">Primero</a>
```

but that will scroll the page to the top, which can be an issue

Or, prevent the default action of the anchor:

```
$("#a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#content").load('index.html');
});
```

Comment: By the way...Do you know how to recode the JQuery function so that it receives the id of the last object clicked?